# "uniform variables in vertex shader do not fit in 512 vectors" error in shader compile

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

In my vertex shader code i have array of mat3x4 structs.
The array is a uniform and even though its total vector num is only 60,
I received a shader compile error: 

"uniform variables in vertex shader do not fit in 512 vectors."

Here is my shader code:

[VertexShader]

```
struct mat3x4{
    highp vec4 v[3];
};

attribute highp vec4 vPosition;
uniform mat3x4 camSkin[20];

void main() {
    // test code
    gl_Position.x = vPosition.x + camSkin[0].v[0].x + camSkin[19].v[2].x;
    gl_Position.y = vPosition.y + camSkin[0].v[0].y + camSkin[19].v[2].y;
    gl_Position.z = vPosition.z + camSkin[0].v[0].z + camSkin[19].v[2].z;
    gl_Position.w = vPosition.w + camSkin[0].v[0].w + camSkin[19].v[2].w;
};
```

[FragmentShader]

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
};
```

I am developing on adreno220 GPU Android smartphone,
and using Android OS 2.3.

How do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't someone known? 
I am troubled very much.